# Filling up a dynamic online form in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, forms, web-scraping, robobrowser

I am working with RoboBrowser on Python and I am trying to fill up a form on a website ([here](http://www.kidzee.com/admissions-at-kidzee/)). Now the thing is that the form is dynamic. If you open up the link, you'll see a row for 'Country', 'State/District', 'City' and 'Location'.

The State/District row depends on which Country you select out of the drop down menu, City depends on State/District and Location depends on City. I want to be able to extract for example 'values' of State/District for a particular value of the country. For example when I write the following code:

```
>>> import re
>>> from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
>>> browser = RoboBrowser()
>>> browser.open('http://http://www.kidzee.com/admissions-at-kidzee/')
>>> form = browser.get_form()
>>> form
<RoboForm siteid=, adunit=, fname=, lname=, email=, mobile=,country=,state=,
city=, location=0, 6_letters_code=, admission_submit=Submit>
>>> form['country'].options
['','1','2'] #The options presented are India and Nepal.
>>>form['country'].value = '1'
>>>form['state'].options
['']
```

Now what I want to do it get all the possible values for `form['state'].value` with `form['country'].value = '1'` (because the list of states depends on the value of country). How do I go about doing that?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: So, there's jquery going behind the scenes, open the network tab and select a country you'll see how the query is send at `http://www.kidzee.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=state` you can just send a request at that url with form data *0* or *1* and you receive the data, quick question . how are you planning to tackle the captcha?

Comment: 1. I am not looking to fill the form. Just obtaining the data (changing values of states) being received when I change the value of the Country.
2. I tried what you said by using `requests.post` with the url in your comment and `data: 1`. What it returned is this:`<option value= "" selected>--Select State--</option>`.

Comment: I am able to retrieve the data now. I just had to use ` 'state': '1'` in the post request as data. It shows all the states in the country now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Upon examining the network log, credits: @P.hunter, I saw that a request was being sent to `http://www.kidzee.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=state` whenever I pressed the Select Country button. So I wrote the following code to fetch the data:

```
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

    url = 'http://www.kidzee.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=state'
    fields = {'state': '1'}  

    r = Request(url, urlencode(fields).encode())
    json = urlopen(r).read().decode()
    print(json)
```

And now I am getting the required states in the country.

Thanks for the right direction @P.hunter.

Comment: heeyyy, awesome buddy, always here for help bless you ;)